# How to find most frequent text with a criteria to not include texts from a range?

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, mode

I am using the formulas `=IFERROR(INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF( J110:J100000<>"",MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0)))),"")`
,  `=IFERROR(INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF(( J110:J100000<>"")*( J110:J100000<>INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF( J110:J100000<>"",MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0))))),MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0)))),"")`
and `=IFERROR(INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF((( J110:J100000<>"")*( J110:J100000<>INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF( J110:J100000<>"",MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0)))))*( J110:J100000<>INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF(( J110:J100000<>"")*( J110:J100000<>INDEX( J110:J100000,MODE(IF( J110:J100000<>"",MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0))))),MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0)))))),MATCH( J110:J100000, J110:J100000,0)))),"")`

to search for the top most, second most and third most occurring text in the array J110:J100000. But how do I fix these formula's with criteria to not search or to ignore any text that is also occurring in the array AA1:AA10? In other words, the results from these formula's should not be present in any of the cells in the array AA1:AA10, ignoring the blanks of course. TIA. Appreciate any help.

Comment: how are you handling ties?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Apologies, but I didn't quite understand which ties are you referring to. But AA1:AA10 and  J110:J100000 have no direct connection. AA1:AA10 is a result of calculations from a different sheet but some of the text in J110:J100000 and AA1:AA10 can be the same which I want these formula's to not look for or ignore. Results from these formula should not be similar to any of the cells in AA1:AA10. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify:  assume "peter", "paul" and "mary" each occur fifty times, and that is the most number of time that any word occurs in column J.  And then you have "george" and "ringo" each occurring forty times, and "ron" and "Excellent" each occurring 20 times.  What do you expect for output?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Oh right, I am interested only in top three names. For this project, its alright to not have all the names. So if there are four names with the same count and even if I miss one it wont matter. Also if I can figure this formula out. I want to try and go till top five. Another option will be to keep removing the names and look for the next top name. Unless you have a better solution. Happy to hear. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @JosWoolley I have the 365 subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=LET(κ,AA1:AA10,ε,J110:J100000,ζ,UNIQUE(ε),η,SORTBY(ζ,COUNTIF(ε,ζ),-1),INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(η,(η<>"")*(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(η,κ,0))))),SEQUENCE(3)))`

The 3 passed to `SEQUENCE` determines the number of results to return.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Joswoolley. I am trying the formula and its giving me the #CALC! error. But when AA1:AA10 is blank it gave me the most occurring texts. Any ideas on how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If you get the `#CALC!` error then that most likely means that there are no entries within `J110:J100000` which are non-blank and not present in `AA1:AA10`

Comment: Of course!!! how silly of me!! Thank you so much for your help. This helps a lot.